# Tastypie using ToOneFields across two ForeignKey relations

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to do this in my resource...

thingy = fields.ToOneField(ThingyResource, 'whatzit__thingy')

ie, traverse an fk. i'm on a resource whos model has an fk to "whatzit", and the "whatzit" model has an fk to "thingy".

that syntax isn't working -- is there a way to do this, or is it not advised, or other?

alternatively, is there a straightforward way to query a resource for the uri for an object?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to just do this:

```
whatzit = fields.ToOneField(WhatzitResource, 'whatzit')
```

and then just dehydrate like this:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['thingy'] = whatzit.thingy
    return bundle
```